# Date wrongly converted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At school we have an internal advent calendar where a new question is displayed every day. To prevent users from accessing future questions I'm fetching time from a server. My current code is as under:

```
$http.get('js/text.json').success(function(data) {
    this.textData = data;
    $http.get('http://api.timezonedb.com/?zone=Europe/Oslo&format=json&key=(private)').success(function(data) {
      this.timeData = data;
      var timestamp = new Date(data.timestamp);
      console.log(timestamp.getDate());
      this.dato = timestamp.getDate();
      this.dagens = this.getSpm(this.dato);
      if (this.dagens === undefined) {
        this.dagens = "Dagens spørsmål har ikke kommet.";
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
```

My problem is that when I convert the fetched timestamp into a date, I get dates from January 1970.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timezonedb.com` returns a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e. the *seconds* since 01.01.1970, javascript's `new Date` expects *milliseconds* since 01.01.1970.

Use `var timestamp = new Date(data.timestamp * 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

You should convert it into miliseconds

```
this.timeData = data*1000;
var timestamp = new Date(data.timestamp);
```

timezonedb.com gives the timestamp in seconds and not in miliseconds.